# How to recolor image object using mask?

Tags: python, opencv, colors, python-imaging-library, image-segmentation

Trying to recolor the hair using a mask. Firstly segmented hair from the main image & trying to make it a realistic one changing HSV value but according to my code the result is not the accurate output that i am looking for. Any solution?

```
img = cv2.imread('model-demo.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img, (256, 256))
_, mask_hair = cv2.threshold(mask_hair, thresh=210, maxval=255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

#cutting specific portion of hair from image
cut_mask = np.invert(mask_hair)
res = np.where(cut_mask, 0, img)

#HSV value changing for new color
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hsv[:,:,0] +=120
hsv[:,:,1] +=60
hsv[:,:,2] -=20
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)

plt.imshow(hsv)
```

The image I have:

[image]

The result according to my code:

[image]

The result I want:

[image]

PART- 2

Also tried to multiply the image mask with color but end the end it doesn't even matter...

```
img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('model-demo.jpg'),(256,256))
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
mask = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('./mask.jpg'),(256,256))

mask_clr = np.zeros([256,256,3],dtype=np.uint8)
mask_clr[np.where((mask_hair==255).all(axis = 2))] = [0, 255, 0]

imgMultiply = cv2.multiply(img,mask_clr)
```

mask_clr --> green mask:

[image]

Comment: You add/subtract colours with`+=` or `-=`. I believe that you're getting an overflow of integer values (e.g. adding 120 causes to go over 255).

Comment: @decadenza Thanks for your reply. As per your suggestion, I tried changing the value within the range but nothing happened ! can you check my PART-2 (edited code above). Where I tried with mask overlay for changing color like realistic but nothing happened !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a simple program for your project

first I used this code to get a mask https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html . This code uses inRange function.

[image]

after that I used the following code to get the results

```
a = np.where(frame_threshold > 0)
ones = np.ones_like(img)
ones[a] = [0.5,1,0.5]
r = img*ones
```

The results I got

[image]

if you change the values to be [0.3,1,1] it will be yellow.

[image]

and it will be red if the value is [0.3,0.1,1]

[image]

and it will be green bluish if the value is [1.5,1.0,0.8]

[image]

Comment: @abbs I appreciate your answer as well as suggestions. Can you please elaborate me these values -> [0.5,1,0.5] ? For mixing any color with rgb is it the right approach?

Comment: Another thing with this line i got error in my code I hade to change it into ones[np.where((mask_hair>0).all(axis = 2))] = [0.5,1,0.5]

Comment: @MSI basically I have factor for (RGB) values. so if I want the color to be green the green value must be the greatest. So if I multiply all R and B by 0.5 and G by one the color will become more green. Hope that answered your question. I would appreciate it if you can vote for my answer if you find my answer helpful.

Comment: Yes, it was! just a little inquiry. If I want it to turn in yellow is it possible?

Comment: yes you can make it yellow. if you changed the values to [0.3,1,1]

Comment: basically the factors are for [B,G,R] so the dominant color shall be the greatest. see the examples I added

Comment: That's great! but somehow I missed the point in generally we change with BRG ->[38,225,242] but how you are measuring the value [0.3,0.1,1] for yellow? Little more addition if I want to decrease the alpha value of color a little more what should do? I tried importing image with alpha value and ones[a] = [0.5,1,0.5, 0.4(alpha)] but nothing happened.

Comment: The color value must be related to the original image. That's why you can see the hair new color is not exactly the same, but darker at some points and brighter at some other.  for example a yellow color is [0,255,255]  to change this to a factors it will be [0,1,1] . in other words you need to dived each value by 255. Btw yellow is not [0.3,0.1,1] it is [0.3,1,1]

Comment: I want to change the BGR dynamically whats the reason I wanted to know about these points. As per your thought orange(BGR) - -> [0, 100, 255] should be [0.3, 100/255, 255/255] isn't it? But it is not turning into orange.